# Get List of Files in Sub Directories for FAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I'm trying to use FAKE to build F# files that are located in several sub directories. The [filesInDirMatching](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-filesystemhelper.html) is from FAKE.

```
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open System.IO
open Fake
open Fake.FileSystemHelper
open Fake.FscHelper

let allDirs = DirectoryInfo(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__).GetDirectories "*"
let all = allDirs |> Array.map(fun d -> filesInDirMatching "Example.fs" d)
```

This all kind of works except that, in the last line, it's creating a 2-dimensional array (since filesInDirMatching creates a new FileDirectory array, I'm guessing). Is it possible to reduce the 2-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: UPDATE: Use `filesInDirMatchingRecursive` for it - https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/FileSystemHelper.fs#L39-39

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess by a 2 dimensional array you mean an array of array (a jagged array).

If so, just replace your `Array.map` with `Array.collect`

Comment: Whoops! You are correct, sir. And I got it to work with this! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten the array into a single dimension with `Array.concat`:

```
let all = allDirs
          |> Array.map(fun d -> filesInDirMatching "Example.fs" d)
          |> Array.concat
```

Comment: I tried and this also can work. Wish I could also set yours as an answer, as well.